# Undefined navigator using React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm getting undefine navigator usign React Native

MessageTabs:

```
 _onPressItem = (item) => { 
  const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

   //console.log(JSON.stringify(item));
  navigate('SingleConversation', {id: item.id})
};
```

In the constructor of SingleConversation i get :

var conversation_id = this.navigation.state.params.id;

I'm getting

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your constructor of SingleConversation:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  // `navigation` is from props, not `this`
  var conversation_id = props.navigation.state.params.id;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting null value, how to fix this @riwu ?

Comment: After doing that i declare variable and call another function and use this     const conversation_id = this.state.conversation_id;
 not working

Comment: Gets null value

Comment: I can't really guess what's wrong without seeing the full code. Can you also log `item.id`?